# icCube - Failed to load Java VM library ... (errno = 193)

Tags: windows, iccube

Starting icCube produces the following error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a mismatch between icCube and the JRE. Most probably icCube is in 64bits and the JRE in 32bits. We advise to :

- Uninstall icCube and the Java JRE
- Download & Install a 64bit version of Java
- Install again icCube

This should fix the problem